# how to launch a file when open the system Ubuntu?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to rolaunch a launch file when i start the Ubuntu system automatically，how can I realize this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277106/how-to-launch-a-file-when-open-the-system-ubuntu?/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think #q193181 is still relevant.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-12-01**:
OK, thank u for you advice